# How to use Variable form one keyword to another keyword in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
*** Keywords ***
JSON Object-Token 
    Create Session     Portal     ${portalUrlData}
    ${auth_token}=  Evaluate    "Basic " +***********************************'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    ${headers}    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded       Authorization=${auth_token}
    ${response}    Post On Session    Portal    /oidc/token    headers=${headers}    data=${tokenData}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    200
    Log    Response: ${response.text}
    **${token}**        Set Variable        ${response.json()['access_token']}

JSON Object-User  
   Create Session    Admin    ${adminUrlData}
   ${headersWithToken}    Create Dictionary        Authorization=Bearer **${token}**   
   ${responseUser}    Post On Session    Admin       /api/users    headers=${headersWithToken}    json=${userDetails}
   Should Be Equal As Strings    ${responseUser.status_code}    201
   Log    Response: ${responseUser.text}    
   ${userid}          Set Variable        ${responseUser.json()['id']}
   ${username}        Set Variable        ${responseUser.json()['username']}
```

I want to use `${token}` variable from keyword JSON Object-Token into another keyword JSON Object-User how to do that?

Comment: One of the solutions is to extend the scope of the variable. By default it is 'local' variable.  The keywords [`Set Test Variable`,  `Set Suite Variable`, and `Set Global Variable`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Using%20variables%20with%20keywords%20creating%20or%20accessing%20variables) could be handy.

Comment: Just in case: Example of last row of your keyword could be: `Set Suite Variable    $token       ${response.json()['access_token']}`

Comment: NB: Probably, you already have considered the idea, that getting a token could be a part of the test setup. E.g. the keyword that gets a token could be added in the Test Setup or Suite Setup section of your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Keywords ***
Token
  [Arguments]  Create Session     Portal     ${portalUrlData}
  ${token} =  bla bla bla your code 
  [Return]  ${token}
```

Comment: The `RETURN   ${token}` could be used since RobotFramework 5.0. I.e. without square brackets. [Doc](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-return-values)

Comment: The question was not syntax, the question was how to pass values ​​between methods

Comment: Yeap, sure, it was just a minor update for your good answer. I.e. IMHO, better to make answers with new syntax than with deprecated one [doc](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-return-setting).